# Docker compose environment variables not picking up in nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a vue app running on the front-end with spring boot backend both on different containers.
I want to dockerize my vuejs app to pass environment variables from the docker-compose file to nginx.

My problem is that my *nginx conf* file is not picking up environment variables from docker-compose.

**Docker Compose File**

```
backend-service:
    container_name: backend-service
    image: backend-service-local
    networks:
      - app-network
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      postgresdb:
        condition: service_healthy

vue-app:
    container_name: vue-app
    image: vue-app-local
    networks:
      - app-network
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      VUE_APP_BASE_URL: http://backend-service:8080
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      backend-service:
        condition: service_started
```

**DOCKER FILE**

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**NGINX CONF**

```
# Run as a less privileged user for security reasons.
user nginx;

# #worker_threads to run;
# "auto" sets it to the #CPU_cores available in the system, and
# offers the best performance.
worker_processes    auto;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    sendfile on;
    
    upstream docker-backend {
        server ${VUE_APP_BASE_URL};
    }

    server {
        # Hide nginx version information.
        server_tokens off;

        listen  80;
        root    /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass  http://docker-backend;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you reading that env var, though? I can't spot any reference to `VUE_APP_BASE_URL` in your `nginx.conf`.

Comment: I just edited it... Please have a  look now !! @Felix

Comment: How can you tell that nginx is not picking up the variable? Do you have an error message? What is the behavior that you are seeing and how does it differ from your expected behavior? The only problem I see here in the config is a potential double `http://` prefix (once set in the env var, once set in the `proxy_pass` declaration).

Comment: hi is it solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please advise [nginx docker image docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) in the `Using environment variables in nginx configuration` section of the page.

The way the nginx docker image deals with environment variables is injecting them in runtime using the configs in the linked page